# How to build an Android version?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I upgraded my phone and would now like to begin breaking my old one.

I went and pulled the [Android Source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and and synced it. All was swell. Next up was to run:

```
envsetup.sh
```

I think this went ok; nothing was displayed so I assume no errors occurred. Now I'm stuck on `lunch'. What do I have to do here?  The docs say to

> Choose which target to build with lunch. The exact configuration can
>   be passed as an argument, e.g.

by running

```
lunch full-eng
```

I did this, but it tells me `full-eng` doesn't exist. So I tried just `lunch` and get

```
No such file: /home/andrew/.lunchrc.
```

What do I have to do to get this to build? Did I fail to download the appropriate resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a control question, when you said you ran `envsetup.sh`, you really meant `source build/envsetup.sh` right? If not, that is likely the cause of your problems.

If that doesn't solve your problem, that is probably because another `lunch` (in your case it looks like http://code.sat.qc.ca/trac/lunch) is invoked. Try uninstalling the other `lunch` or at least remove it from your `PATH` to ensure that it is `lunch` from Android that is run.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove linux package python-launch and re-run envsetup.sh.

Answer (score 0):

Once I setup my build environment, I used

```
 source build/envsetup.sh
 lunch
```

Without anything behind, it will give you a list to choose from.